Simultaneous operations of LHC and LIGO
I once asked a question regarding atomic clocks near particle accelerators.
Where the high-energy of the accelerators would be considered a source of stress energy. I was made to understand that the stress energy would be far too small to Induce significant amount of curvature of spacetime for the atomic clock to detect non-neglible time dillation.
This time I would like to consider the possibility of detecting such small gravitaional effects through the use of LIGO (since LIGO can detect very faint gravitaional waves coming from vast distance).
So the question I now raise is as follows:
Say the LHC and LIGO are both operating simultaneously, only a few distance apart may not be too close though. Would LIGO register the very faint gravitaional wave signal coming from the high energy collision or acceleration? (knowing this time we have the advantage of distance being closer, unlike with faint waves coming from vast distance.)

I don't even think we can detect our own solar systems gravitational waves, so I doubt we can detect those from other sources nearby that would be even weaker. Maybe someone can come along with a better determination of an answer.

I do not think this to be the case. First, even though energy densities in the LHC can be very high the total energy is incredibly small.  Second LIGO is only sensitive to certain wavelengths of gravitational waves which I would guess  are vastly different from what LHC may produce.

LIGO is not a single detector - it is actually a pair of detectors on opposite sides of the USA. To reliably detect cosmological gravitational waves you need two detectors at a large distance from one another so that you can filter out local effects, which will affect one detector but not the other.
Any gravitational waves emitted by the LHC will be very low in amplitude and no different from other local events - there is nothing special about the LHC that would make it emit gravitational waves with a specific signature.
So if you move one LIGO detector close to the LHC, any gravitational waves emitted by the LHC will be filtered out. And if you move both LIGO detectors close to the LHC then you cannot distinguish any gravitational waves emitted by the LHC from other local background "noise" which will swamp any signal in both detectors.

This is a side point, but the LIGO/Virgo instruments are well understood enough now that there are cases of detections based on a single operating interferometer, like GW190425. However, I don't think anyone would believe an event like that without gaining experience from previous coincident detections in multiple interferometers, so I think your answer is essentially right, just wanted to add this as a footnote.

Then I guess all shots at considering particle accelerators and colliders such as LHC as a source of stress energy to induce gravity or spacetime curvature will always lead to negligible signatures.
Both the Time dillation with atomic clocks and the use of LIGO for gravitaional waves/Length contraction.

It would have been nice though, (to induce and have a little bit significant level of control over spacetime curvature, without always having to look to the skies...LoL).

@PreciousAdegbite We do have a little bit of control over spacetime curvature. Any time you move any mass around it changes the geometry (and local time dilation) a little bit. Everything has mass, and many easily-movable things have much more mass than the LHC beam. This page says the total LHC beam energy at 7 TeV is 362 MJ, which (dividing by c²) is about 4 µg.
